# setting my XML for Android to have a central content area + top and bottom data

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I have 4 rows of data.

```
<text input>
<content area>
<option row 1>
<option row 2>
```

and they look right but when i try to set the height of  it will not work correctly and push the stuff below it, off the visible area.  I was trying to do a linearLayout, and i was thinking maybe to use GridLayout or A relativeLayout.

What do you think?  I was just trying the GridLayout and it was supplying errors, because my target api/version.

More or less i am trying to do something like this:

```
--------------------------------------
|             text input             |
--------------------------------------
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|              View                  |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------
|               Options 1            |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------
|                Options 2           |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------
```

but when i am writing it up, it will do:

```
--------------------------------------
|             text input             |
--------------------------------------
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|              View                  |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
|                                    |
--------------------------------------
```

**Edit:  Accidently deleted the XML files, will have to reconstruct.  Wont be done for a few days, as there is a task that just came in with high Priority.**

Comment: at the very least post the malfunctioning xml

Comment: Post the XML file up. More than likely you've set the height of your Content View area to fill_parent so the option rows do not have enough space to be shown. Still, post the xml so we can offer some more insight man

Comment: ill post the XML when i have it.  It was deleted after the question was asked.  I will get around to posting the XML within the next few days when I have time to redesign it.  Work is having me shift to something else for the time being.